# Can one catch up fast of previous years?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I didn't know that you should catch up on any fast you have missed in Ramadan before the next Ramadan arrives. Therefore I have a lot of days to catch up ad I have even lost count of the exact number of days. Can I catch these up before the next Ramadan arrives or will I have to make the payments for not completing fasts?

Comment: I assume the sites below could be profitable for you to read them. http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa9030 and http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa9411

Comment: you catch up before the next ramzan comes. Payment is for those who cannot fast any more.

Answer (score 1):

First, I appreciate your keenness to complete the fast, God willing
Sheikh Ibn Baz says in the matter of forgetting the days of fasting following

And the meaning of his words that you have three things:

**First** repentance to delay fasting.

**Secondly**, you must fast the days of which you are certain

**Thirdly**, you have to feed a day for each day of delay if you can afford.

The origin of the fatwa is in Arabic here [The source of fatwa](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/fatawa/561)
and Allah know

Answer (score 1):

The ruling on making up missed prayers and fasts, depends on the reason why they were missed. Here is a breakdown and the reason:

❶ - **Intentional**: If you miss an act of worship intentionally (meaning, you couldn't be bothered, were lazy, were ignorant, so on), then you can not make them up later. The reason for this is that each prayer (fast is similar) is for a particular and defined time (year, day). You cannot arbitrarily choose to perform them at another time because they have been commanded to occur at specific times. Allah is the One who determined when we would fast, and hence we cannot choose to do them at other times by choice (intentional). The known reference, eg, in terms of salah, is:

> 4:103. إن الصلاة كانت على المؤمنين كتابا موقوتا  ...Verily, the prayer
>   is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours.

**In such cases, you have to only repent sincerely (with the known conditions of repentance, eg sincerity, not returning to the sin, and so on). Good deeds (eg, voluntary prayers and fasts) is also helpful in repentance.**

❷ - **Unintentional**: If your prayer or fast was missed unintentionally, (eg, you were forced to miss it, you were genuinely tired and asleep or overslept, in battle where the Prophet once or twice prayed later due to it and cursed the disbelievers for keeping them engaged in battle till the correct time passed, etc) - then in SUCH UNINTENTIONAL circumstances, you make up the act of worship as soon as possible. (You can refer to the answer by Tarek or in other places for the penalties of late or unknown fasts/prayers etc in fatawa journals).

If this was due to period and a large amount of time passed without making up the fasts, then:

> "She has to ask Allaah for forgiveness and repent to Him, and she has
>   to fast the days that she missed and feed one poor person for each
>   day, as was stated by a number of the companions of the Prophet (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him). This means giving half a saa’,
>   which is equivalent to one and a half kilograms." https://islamqa.info/en/40695

Comment: Then all of us should intentionally not pray and just repent cool! But strange logic.

Comment: "And just repent" ? I encourage you to learn the conditions of repentance, the issue of sinning with the intention of repenting, and so on. Also, not everyone has the chance to "just repent" later, even though every single human at the time of death wishes to repent. And not every repentance will be accepted (which is why there are conditions of repentance in the first place). Please understand my answer before raising objections. But I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: Your answer only shows a single view. One can easily do a sin and sincerly repent and redo it it is widely addressed and affirmed in ahadith. The acceptance is something we indeed don't know about as it is in Allah's hands,

Comment: So you expect every answer to show every single view ever brought forward in the history of Islam? My answers are based on proof which I quoted. Not everyone will accept it, and that is not my concern. what you are suggesting, regarding sinning then repenting, does not work when it is intentional, and planning such against Allah is worse. You cannot plan against Allah. "One can easily do a sin and sincerely repent" - IF Allah gives them a chance. And if He gives that chance, then yes, it is good and a mercy upon additional mercy. I think you might be out of your depth in such issues.

Comment: No I just want to point at the fact that this view doesn't sound logical at least not without any explanation. So it was a help to improve your edit. IMO any view is accepted as far is you clearly mention which scholars hold this view. The majority of scholars consider praying qada' necessary in any case as the salat is fard on you so one should regard it as debt, This doesn't mean it will be accepted without repentance.

Comment: I did mention proof. The proof is very clear, EVERY salah and fast is for a set time. You cant just choose to pray it another time or else it wont be accepted. If you cannot understand the proof, you are free to blindly follow some scholar whose view you consider more reasonable. It doesnt change the fact that the acts of worship have a defined time and Will NOT be accepted at any other arbitrarily chosen time. Or else the deen collapses.

Comment: That is the basis of what follows. In that if the salah or fast has a specific time, and you willingly let that time frame elapse, should you be allowed to pray or fast to make that up whenever you want? Does that mean you have fulfilled the conditions of the prayer or fast, of which the time frame is part of the deen? Clearly not. So there is no "making up" such acts of worship, but there is repentance and not returning to the sin, and other conditions of repentance. I hope that is clear now.

Comment: That's an interpretation not a proof. AS other scholars say you should pray missed prayers in their time ... an other interpretation.

Comment: I also said we pray missed prayers.... if they are unintentionally missed. But we will leave the discussion at this point. You are free to disagree if you wish. Guidance cannot be forced, even in the face of clear irrefutable evidence.

Answer (score -1):

Initially I ought to mention that it is necessary to take the Qazaa  (القضا) of the days which delayed its Qazaa (of Ramadhan) for a year or several years. Secondly it is necessary to point that it should pay one Mod for each day (to poor people (الفقیر)).

Of course you ought to catch them up as you said if I can catch these up before the next Ramadan arrives. But as far as I know, you must pay its Kafarah (الکفاره)  as well as catching them up.

---

**References:**

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa9030

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa47048

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa47048

Answer (score -2):

You should catch up on any fast you have missed in Ramadan before the next Ramadan arrives else you do a payments or buy a food for poor people. there are an amount for each day.

Read this to know why you should not miss any fast

[الإعجاز العلمي في فرض الصيام](http://www.weziwezi.com/news/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B9%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B6-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85/)

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. References don't speak for themselves and you cannot expect visitors of an English site to be able to read and understand Arabic, so you'd better elaborate an answer -in your own words- based on the linked article. Please consider taking our tour, checking our help center to learn more about how this site. And read How to Answer to learn what we expect for an answer to be good.